# how to configure jenkins master slave where master is on linux and slave on windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, master-slave

How can i configure jenkins master slave
Master is on linux and slave is on windows
I need to execute a file on slave through master
I don't have much idea about jenkins so i need full direction please.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the docs. You need the windows slave agent installed.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines